# Video file format not recognized in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to add a video file in a  raw folder that I created in the resource folder, but  when I copy and paste the video file in the raw folder, it is not recognized by Android Studio. The icon of the video file displayed by Android Studio is a text file icon, and when I open the file, the following is shown:

Scrrenshot of the issue

[image: 1]

I tried it with other video files, but the same thing still happened. I saw similar questions dating from last year and previous years on here, I tried all their solutions, but none of them worked.
Please, what should I do to make Android Studio recognize the file as a video file?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The file cannot be played in Android Studio,
Because it does not contain multimedia player.
Go to the file path and run it externally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is, I tried to play the video from the app that I am working on. When I compiled the app together with the video resource, it launched on my device but the operating system reported that the video cannot be played. So the root of the problem is from android studio.

Comment: Have you tried another extension for the video format? (mp4 to avi)

Comment: No, I have not.  The avi video file format is not supported by default in the android operating system.